# A fragment (list) that changes another fragment

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

Two fragments that work together as a sort of menu; the top fragment should hold an ImageView that is changed by a list that is inside the bottom fragment. How do I go about doing this? Do I need to use a RecyclerView?

I'm not sure where to begin, would I have to make a generic Fragment or make a fragment for each list item. If I can go with the generic option; how would I go about doing something like that? Any help would be appreciated I'm really lost.

[How it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWAaw.png)

Comment: Your idea sounds fine to me - you don't nee to use two Fragments, just one would do it, but you could, and doing so may give you more flexibility in future. A `RecyclerView` would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reasoning

You can go with either.

So basically, you can write any layout file and you'll be able to inflate it either in a `Fragment`, an `Activity` or just as a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` it doesn't really matter from that point of view (layout file).

#### Fragments are a great choice because:

- They allow for easy reutilization of all of the code englobing the `Fragment`
- They are instantiable, unlike `Activity`; which basically means that you don't have to go through the implementation of the `Parcelable` patter to pass complex objects between them (Fragment <--> Fragment || Fragment <--> Activity)

#### An `Activity` would just suffice:

Implementing a Fragment is really nice, but if you just don't need it then you're writing boilerplate code that doesn't serve any real use... So don't do that :P

## Sample code

### Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".StackOverflowSample">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/your_image_view"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/your_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Kotlin code:

```
class StackOverflowSample : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stack_overflow_sample)
        recycler.apply {
            adapter = SwitcherAdapter(
                arrayOf(
                    Data("F", R.drawable.froyo, ::onItemClicked),
                    Data("O", R.drawable.oreo, ::onItemClicked)
                )
            )
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@StackOverflowSample)
        }
    }

    fun onItemClicked(data: Data) {
        your_image_view.setImageResource(data.resourceDrawable)
    }
}


data class Data(val textViewText: String, val resourceDrawable: Int, val callback: ((Data) -> Unit)? = null)

class SwitcherAdapter(val dataset: Array<Data>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SimpleViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.simple_viewholder_item, parent, false)
        return SimpleViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SimpleViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bindTo(dataset[position])
}

class SimpleViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val textView= view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

    fun bindTo(data: Data) {
        data.callback?.let { call ->
            super.itemView.setOnClickListener { call.invoke(data) }
        }
        textView.text = data.textViewText
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow man thanks this is very detailed and helpful, cleared up a lot of questions I had in my head. Actually I do have to use fragments, it is for an assignment otherwise I obviously would not bother. I'm currently not near a PC but when I get home I'll try to work around this and do this with fragments

Comment: Let me know if you need some guidance on the `Activity` that will be hosting your `Fragment`s :)

Comment: I'm now having a problem with a lateint variable not being initialized :( Is there somewhere I can contact you to take a look so we don't side-track this thread?

Comment: Feel free to email me at miquelrc95@outlook.es

Answer (score 1):

I would use a RecyclerView for the list for sure.

As for the top, if you are just replacing an image I would recommend just using an ImageView on the main activity.

Then setup an interface in your RecyclerView adapter that passes the selected object to your fragment, and then back to your activity. Then in that callback, update the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Observer pattern.

When you click an item of your bottom fragment's RecyclerView, notify all subscribers with the new value selected. Then, on the activity you set the top fragment as a subscriber and finally, on the top fragment's callback you make the changes in the ImageView.

And yes, it's highly recommended for you to use a RecyclerView to handle the items as a list.

PS.: you will only need to use fragments if you want to use either that RecyclerView or that ImageView with that same behaviour in other activities, otherwise it's totally fine to keep them straight in the activity.